# Разрешение экрана в Edubuntu 12.10

Tags: драйвер, экран, ubuntu

Доброе время суток! Уже спрашивал, но, видно, неправильно. Пару месяцев назад установил Edubuntu 12.10, все устраивает, но недавно попытался подключить проектор и обнаружил, что в этом дистрибутиве экран ноутбука имеет всего одно разрешение: 1280*800. А проектор такого разрешения не имеет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить разрешение экрана ноутбука?

Answer (score 1):

При подключенном проекторе в консоль делаешь xrandrПолучаешь что-то типа

> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 4096 x 4096VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm   1360x768       59.8
>    1024x768       60.0
>    800x600        60.3     56.2
>    848x480        60.0
>    640x480        59.9     59.9
>    1280x1024_60.00   59.9*

Только у тебя будет еще и VGA2 или VGA-2 или еще как-нибудь с единственным разрещением 1280*800Это название твоего выхода на проектор. Возможные названия интерфейсов:

- LVDS1 — экран ноутбука;
- VGA1 — экран, подключаемый через VGA;
- DVI1 — экран, подключаемый через DVI;

Запоминаем его.

1. Создаем новое разрешение Например 1024x768 50 Гц

> cvt 1024 768 50

На выходе получаем строку типа

> 1024x768 49.98 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 39.63 kHz; pclk: 52.00 MHzModeline "1024x768_50.00"   52.00  1024 1072 1168 1312  768 771 775 793 -hsync +vsync

Далее все просто

```
xrandr  --newmode "1024x768_50.00"   52.00  1024 1072 1168 1312  768 771 775 793 -hsync +vsync xrandr --addmode VGA2 1024x768_50.00 xrandr --output VGA2 --mode
```